# How do I share a large read-only object across Dask distributed workers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask, concurrent.futures, dask-distributed

### The Problem

I'm trying to send a 2GB CPython read-only object (can be pickled) to dask distributed workers via `apply()`. This ends up consuming a lot of memory for processes/ threads (14+ GB).

Is there a way to load the object only once into memory and have the workers concurrently use the object?

### More details about the problem

I have 2 Dask series Source_list and Pattern_list, containing 7 Million and 3 Million strings respectively. I'm trying to find all sub-string matches in Source_list (7M) from Pattern_list(3M).

To speed up the sub-string search, I use the [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/) package to create a Cpython data-structure (a class object) from Pattern_list (The object is pickle-able).

### Things I've tried

1. running with the single dask scheduler takes about 2.5 hours to process, but finishes with correct results.
2. running with dask distributed normally results in:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to 
store to disk. Perhaps some other process is leaking memory? Process memory:  
2.85 GB -- Worker memory limit: 3.00 GB
```

3. running with dask distributed with memory limit increased to 8GB/16GB:

   - **Threads**

     ```
     distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no 
     data to  store to disk. Perhaps some other process is leaking 
     memory? 
     Process memory:  14.5 GB -- Worker memory limit: 16.00 GB 
     distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
     ```
   - **Processes**
     Takes more than 2.5 hours to process and I've never seen it finish (left it running for 8+ hours before cancelling). It also consumes 10+ GB of 
     memory
4. Using the vectorized string operation `Source_list.str.find_all(Pattern_list)` takes more than 2.5 hours.
5. Storing the object in a global variable and calling it results in the same error as in point 3 for processes and threads.
6. Using map_partitions + loop/map on Source_list gives same results as point 3.

### Dask Distributed Code

```
# OS = Windows 10
# RAM = 16 GB
# CPU cores = 8
# dask version 1.1.1

import dask.dataframe as dd
import ahocorasick
from dask.distributed import Client, progress

def create_ahocorasick_trie(pattern_list):
    A = ahocorasick.Automaton()
    for index, item in pattern_list.iteritems():
         A.add_word(item,item)
    A.make_automaton()
    return A 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client(memory_limit="12GB",processes=False)

    # Using Threading, because, the large_object seems to get copied in memory 
    # for each process when processes = True

    Source_list = dd.read_parquet("source_list.parquet") 
    Pattern_list = dd.read_parquet("pattern_list.parquet")

    # Note: 'source_list.parquet' and 'pattern_list.parquet' are generated via dask

    large_object = create_ahocorasick_trie(Pattern_list)

    result = Source_list.apply(lambda source_text: {large_object.iter(source_text)}, meta=(None,'O'))

    # iter() is an ahocorasick Cpython method

    progress(result.head(10))

    client.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to wrap it in a dask.delayed call

```
big = dask.delayed(big)
df.apply(func, extra=big)
```

Dask will move it around as necessary and treat it as its own piece of data.  That being said, it will need to exist on every worker, so you should have significantly more RAM per worker than that thing takes up.  (at least 4x or so more).

Comment: Can I use the same technique for map or map_partitions ? I can't see `extra=` argument in API.

Comment: Yes, this works for those methods as well.  I'm using the term `extra` above as a placeholder for any keyword argument to your user defined function.